# VisualVM GC Activity is reported as zero

Tags: jvm, profiling, cpu-usage, visualvm

I am using OpenJDK, Java 8, VisualVM 1.2.1 (same JDK for application being profiled). In VisualVM, under the `Monitor` tab, we are able to see `CPU usage` and `% of GC Activity`. The issue is, `% of GC Activity` is always 0 when `VisualGC` is reporting GC activities as usual. I want to get stats on % of time spent on GC activity. How can I fix this or is there other ways to get this stat?

Comment: Your problem is that the garbage collection takes too little CPU time?

Comment: GC is happening so how can the metric always be 0%?

Comment: Just rounded down. Having less than 1% is not unusual.